# Troubleshooting a next js build - Static worker unexpectedly exited

Tags: next.js

I am running a next js build. Towards the end of the build process (note this is a build error, not a runtime error), I get this error:

`Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM`

I have tried running with the --debug flag (`npx next build --debug`), but this doesn't give any more information.

Is there any way of troubleshooting what is causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the .next directory before building fixed this. No idea why.